# Security: Better to run Docker on VM or bare metal?

Tags: security, docker

Strictly from the perspective of security - had these questions:

1. Which is better, running Docker on a VM or running or an actual machine?
2. Are there security risks when running on a VM that are not present when running on actual, real hardware?
3. Does the OS of the VM or actual hardware matter with respect to this issue?

I am assuming Docker 1.12+

Comment: https://blog.docker.com/2016/04/physical-virtual-container-deployment/ and https://blog.docker.com/2016/05/vm-or-containers/ look relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Security wise, Virtualization gives you more separation. There is a tiny overhead when you are using VMs, but you have the advantages of `virtualization`, like easier management, better usage of resources, snapshots, HA, and etc.
2. No. `Virtualization` is an old technology that nowdays everyone uses it. You just need to follow the best practices.
3. You need to use an updated popular linux distribution and keep it up to date overtime. My personal preference is `debian`, `Jessie` at the time of the writing, And you can join security `mailing lists` to get informed about CVE's and respective patches. But feel free to use `Ubuntu`,`Centos`,`RHEL`,`SUSE`.

Comment: 1) is actually not true in general. If separation of docker instances is important, running instances in separate VMs has a big advantage. Even if an attacker compromises the logical separation provided by docker, if a different instance or group of instances run in a separate VM, an attacker potentially has to compromise the hypervisor too to gain access. That may be a significant difference.

Comment: By instances you mean containers, residing on a docker host. If an attacker compromise a VM, he can probably compromise the physical equivalence. same linux distribution with same updates. Now, If the attacker can compromise your hypervisers, He's in total control, But doing that should be extremely hard on updated commercial hypervisors like `ESXi` or even on top Opensource hypervisors like `KVM`.

Comment: Yes I meant containers, sorry. And we are talking about the same thing I think. It may be easier for an attacker to compromise a container (Docker itself, which is just a logical separation in the kernel) than compromising the hypervisor. So if you have two different VMs with each having a Docker host and each host having several containers, it will be significantly harder for an attacker to compromise a container in a VM after breaking one in the other VM. This setup would provide more separation.

Comment: I agree, But let me be clear, If the attacker compromise the VM, he has already full control over containers on that vm. He can execute commands, access to the files and everything.

Comment: Agreed, but that's the point. He still doesn't have that control on the other VM, and it may be quite difficult to compromise the hypervisor and gain access to the other VM.

Comment: Edited the answer.